# how to load .JSON file to RealSense D435 camera using C++ and intel API

Tags: c++, json, depth, realsense

I'm trying to tune my depth camera (RealSense D435) to get better/different depth data. Therefore i want to experiment with the different pre sets from intel's adviced parameter configuration as explained in [the intel SDK](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/wiki/D400-Series-Visual-Presets). Intel advices to use the pre sets and to **not** try to tune and fiddle with the 50+ paramaters yourself.

As much as i'd like to ignore that comment of intel, i am unable to even upload/read/process the  pre set configuration pre sets which are provided as a .JSON file (C++). Is anyone able to show a code snippet in which a .JSON file is succesfully used to change the advanced settings of the generated depth image of a  Realsense D400 series camera?

Comment: Does the Intel SDK include a JSON lib? If not, get one first. [RapidJSON](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson) and [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) are two popular libs.

Comment: Yes, the JSON libs are provided on (https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/wiki/D400-Series-Visual-Presets)

Comment: Great, then show the code you're written to try to read the preset configuration as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, i do like to see an example on how to do this since i have no clue.

From the rs_option.h headerfile i can find the following declerations:
 /** \brief For RS400 devices: provides optimized settings (presets) for specific types of usage. */
    typedef enum rs2_rs400_visual_preset
    {
        RS2_RS400_VISUAL_PRESET_REMOVE_IR_PATTERN,
        RS2_RS400_VISUAL_PRESET_COUNT

    } rs2_rs400_visual_preset;
    const char* rs2_rs400_visual_preset_to_string(rs2_rs400_visual_preset preset);

Comment: I am sorry, i am having some trouble with using enter and shift+enter while typing a comment and have reached my maximum number of edits.

Comment: Another code snippet i found in rs_advanced_mode.hpp reading a most promising decleration:
 `
void load_json(const std::string& json_content)
        {
            rs2_error* e = nullptr;
            rs2_load_json(_dev.get(),
                          json_content.data(),
                          (unsigned int)json_content.size(),
                          &e);
            rs2::error::handle(e);
        } `
Can anyone explain on how to either use the pre set configurations of my previous comment or how to use the above described load_json function?

Comment: Dont add it as comment. Edit your original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out how to do it and here is the code snippet including some extra image retrieving code that has to be put in Main():

```
// Obtain a list of devices currently present on the system
context ctx;
auto devices = ctx.query_devices();
size_t device_count = devices.size();
if (!device_count)
{
    cout <<"No device detected. Is it plugged in?\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// Get the first connected device
auto dev = devices[0];

// Enter advanced mode
   if (dev.is<rs400::advanced_mode>())
   {
       // Get the advanced mode functionality
       auto advanced_mode_dev = dev.as<rs400::advanced_mode>();

       // Load and configure .json file to device
       ifstream t("./presets/ShortRangePreset.json");
       string str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
       advanced_mode_dev.load_json(str);
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "Current device doesn't support advanced-mode!\n";
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

//Contruct a pipeline which abstracts the device
    rs2::pipeline pipe;
    rs2::device selected_device = dev;
    auto depth_sensor = selected_device.first<rs2::depth_sensor>();

    //Create a configuration for configuring the pipeline with a non default profile
    rs2::config cfg;

    //Add desired streams to configuration
    cfg.enable_stream(RS2_STREAM_INFRARED,  ImageWidth_px, ImageHeight_px, RS2_FORMAT_Y8, FrameRate);
    cfg.enable_stream(RS2_STREAM_DEPTH,     ImageWidth_px, ImageHeight_px, RS2_FORMAT_Z16, FrameRate);

    //Instruct pipeline to start streaming with the requested configuration
    pipe.start(cfg);

    // Camera warmup - dropping several first frames to let auto-exposure stabilize
    rs2::frameset frames;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //Wait for all configured streams to produce a frame
        frames = pipe.wait_for_frames();
    }

    bool quit = false;
    char key;

    while (!quit){

        frames = pipe.wait_for_frames();

        //Get each frame
        rs2::frame          ir_frame    = frames.first(RS2_STREAM_INFRARED);
        rs2::depth_frame    depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame();

        // Creating OpenCV matrix from IR image
        Mat ir      (Size(ImageWidth_px, ImageHeight_px), CV_8UC1,  (void*)ir_frame.get_data(),     Mat::AUTO_STEP);
        Mat depth   (Size(ImageWidth_px, ImageHeight_px), CV_16UC1, (void*)depth_frame.get_data(),  Mat::AUTO_STEP);

        // etc the rest of your code on how you want to edit/process the images
        }
```

Comment: This is great, but I've just tried this and it doesn't appear to be actually applying the JSON settings to the device. I can save/serialize the device's current settings nicely, but loading with various methods stills seems to fail silently.   ```advanced_mode_dev.load_json(str);``` appears to succeed but actually it doesn't apply to the device.